# Are JWTs stored in cookies safe?

Tags: java, cookies, jersey, jwt

I'm trying to make a JWT-based authentication process.

1. Started Jersey REST service on Jetty
2. The user posts with username and password at `/users/login`
3. A JWT based on secret key is generated at the server and stored in a cookie
4. The client can now read the cookie for other actions, send a request with `Authorization: Bearer ${jwt}` header to `/users/profile`
5. If the `jwt`, by signature, is valid, the user information is returned, else respond with `Unauthorized`

Now, I just realized; how is this safe? Can't ***any*** user simply read the cookie from the browser and curl request to `/users/profile` and it will be valid?

I'm really still a newbie in this, so could you please explain? Here's some simple test code

```
@Path("users")
public class UserResources {
    @Path("login")
    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response loginUser(UserInput userInput) {
        String compactJws = Jwts.builder().setSubject(userInput.getUsername()).claim("name", userInput.getName())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, Server.SECRECT_KEY).compact();

        return Response.status(Status.OK).cookie(new NewCookie("jwt", compactJws)).entity(compactJws).build();
    }

    @Path("profile")
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Response getUser(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String compactJws) {
        try {
            if (compactJws == null || compactJws.trim().isEmpty() || !compactJws.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                throw new SignatureException("Invalid access token");
            }
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(Server.SECRECT_KEY)
                    .parseClaimsJws(compactJws.substring("Bearer ".length()));
            return Response.ok(new String("Subject: " + claims.getBody().getSubject() + "\nName: " + claims.getBody().get("name"))).build();
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right, if a user has access to your cookies, then he can use your session and authentication details. But that's basically the same for all cookie based authentication technologies. But since the cookies are stored in your user profile, you have more problems, if another user can access this (e.g. accessing saved passwords in your browser etc.)

Answer (score 10):

Validating the signature guarantees that the JWT hasn't been forged or tampered with. As you guessed, the JWT can still be *stolen*. If someone steals the token, they can make impersonate your user and make requests.

There are three important things to do:

1. **Use HTTPS** - end-to-end TLS prevents someone intercepting or sniffing the requests on the wire and stealing the token.
2. **Store tokens securely on the client** - If you store your token in a cookie, *make sure* to use the HttpOnly flag to prevent theft via XSS, and use CSRF protection on all your forms. See [Cookies vs. HTML5 Web Storage](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) for a deeper explanation.
3. **Expire the tokens** - if all else fails, and a token does get stolen, a sensible expiration (`exp` claim) will ensure that there's only a limited window of time that the token can be used to cause damage.